# How to extract the first two column and then delete partial info in the second column?

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to get some info from my file using awk and sed, but not sure how to make it work.

Here is my data look like:

```
00020dfa-549d-43e4-877d-d3dcbc212fe5    Pleosporales_sp|HE820879|SH1523966.08FU|reps|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Pleosporales;f__unidentified;g__unidentified;s__Pleosporales_sp   90.099  707 1680    1195    39  24
```

And the expected output is like this

```
00020dfa-549d-43e4-877d-d3dcbc212fe5    k__Fungi;   p__Ascomycota;  c__Dothideomycetes; o__Pleosporales;    f__unidentified;    g__unidentified;    s__Pleosporales_sp
```

So basically, I only want the data for the first two columns, and in the second column, I only want the information starting from k with tab after all the ";".

I tried the code as below:

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $1, $2}' infile.tab |
    sed -e '|' -e '|' -e '|' -e '|' -e 'D' > outfile.tab
```

But couldn't get the expected output. It will be appreciated if anyone could give me some advice!

Comment: `perl -nale 'for ($F[1]) { s/^.*\|//; s/;/;\t/g } print "$F[0] $F[1]"'`?

Comment: Thanks for reply! How do I specify the input and output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `awk`

```
$ awk '{gsub(/.*\|/,"",$2);   # remove everything upto the last pipe from $2
        gsub(/;/,";\t",$2);   # add space after semicolon in $2
        print $1 "\t" $2}' file

00020dfa-549d-43e4-877d-d3dcbc212fe5    k__Fungi;       p__Ascomycota;       c__Dothideomycetes;  \
o__Pleosporales;        f__unidentified;     g__unidentified;        s__Pleosporales_sp
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simpler AWK, otherwise not very different from @karakfa's solution:

```bash
awk '
  BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "\t"
  }
  {
    sub(/.*\|/, "", $2)
    gsub(/;/, ";\t", $2)
    print $1, $2
  }
  ' infile.tab > outfile.tab
```

Output:

```
00020dfa-549d-43e4-877d-d3dcbc212fe5    k__Fungi;       p__Ascomycota;  c__Dothideomycetes;     o__Pleosporales;        f__unidentified;        g__unidentified;      s__Pleosporales_sp
```

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` solution (if you use `gnu` `sed` you can replace all `$(printf '\t')` simply by `\t`:

```
sed -E "s/([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+).*/\1/;s/[^[:blank:]]*\|//;s/;/;$(printf '\t')/g;s/[[:blank:]]+/$(printf '\t')/;s/[[:blank:]]+$//" infile.tab > outfile.tab
```

**Output:**

```
00020dfa-549d-43e4-877d-d3dcbc212fe5    k__Fungi;   p__Ascomycota;  c__Dothideomycetes; o__Pleosporales;    f__unidentified;    g__unidentified;    s__Pleosporales_sp
```

**Explanations:**

- `s/([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+).*/\1/` will keep only the 2 first fields
- `s/[^[:blank:]]*\|//` will delete the everything in the 2nd field until reaching `k__Fungi`
- `s/;/;$(printf '\t')/g;` add a tab after each `;`
- `s/[[:blank:]]+/$(printf '\t')/` remove all spaces are replace by a tab to separate first and 2 field (this can be omitted if those 2 fields are already separated by a tab
- `s/[[:blank:]]+$//"` delete trailing blanks.